# How to put a moving gif image in Canvas using Class in Python 3.x

Tags: python, class, canvas, tkinter, gif

```
from tkinter import *
from time import *
import os

class gui(Canvas):
    def _init_(self,parent):
        Canvas.__init__(self,parent)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH)
        root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW&quo­t;", self.close)
    def image(self):
        self.giflist=[]
        self.imagelist=[All frames of the gif image]
        for image in self.imagelist:
            self.photo=PhotoImage(file=image)
            self.giflist.append(self.photo)
        self.label=Label(self,fg="black",font=("arial",20,"italic"))
        self.label1=Label(self,bd=0)
    def Run(self):
        for gif in self.giflist:
            self.delete(ALL)
            self.label.config(text=asctime)
            self.label.text=asctime()
            self.label.pack()
            self.label1.config(image=gif)
            self.label1.image=gif
            self.label1.pack()
            self.update()
            sleep(0.1)
    def close(self):
        os._exit(0)

root=Tk()
frame=Canvas(root)
g=gui(frame)
g.image()
while True:
    g.Run()
root.mainloop()
```

When the code is executed the tkinter window is blank. I know to put the gif image without using class but I want to know what is the wrong in this code.

I am sorry if its too obivious or simple. I am using Python 3.5.

The code for putting gif image without class is given below.

```
from tkinter import *
from time import *

root=Tk()
frame=Canvas(root)
frame.pack()
imagelist=[All frames of gif image]
giflist=[]
for image in imagelist:
    photo=PhotoImage(file=image)
    giflist.append(photo)
l=Label(frame,bd=0)
while True:
    for gif in giflist:
        l.config(image=gif)
        l.image=gif
        l.pack()
        sleep(0.1)
        frame.update()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "I know to put the gif image without using class ". Are you saying you have a working version that doesn't use a class? Can you show that too? I'm having difficulty determining what this code is trying to do.

Comment: When you say "moving image", do you mean you want the image to move across the screen, or does "moving image" mean "play a sequence of images like a movie"?

Comment: @Kevin Yes sure I'll send you the link of it by today

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I meant to play a sequence of images like a movie

Comment: @Kevin https://m.youtube.com/results?q=encryption%20and%20decryption%20of%20text%20python%203.5&sm=3   check the code for the first window. There you will find how to put moving gif images. Else if you want I will send you the code for just for putting gif image

Comment: If by "send you", you mean, "edit into the body of my question", yes, that is what I wanted you to do. Not that it matters much now since your question already has a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the gif and rename in numerical order and put the imagens in a folder (images) in the same dir of the script... And done. Don't use time.sleep, always use self.after on tkinter, but if you need to use time you need to call the function with self.after and in the function thats have time.sleep you need to call self.update() below.

```
#IMPORTS
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    import os
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    print("[OK] Imports")
except ValueError as error:
    print(error)
    quit()

imagesFiles = []
atualFrame = 0

#GET IMAGES FROM FOLDER
def getImageList():

    global imagesFiles

    for files in os.listdir("./images"):
        imagesFiles.append(files.split(".")[0])

    imagesFiles = sorted(imagesFiles, key = int)

#CHANGE FRAMES
def changeFrames(self):

    global atualFrame

    self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("./images/" + imagesFiles[atualFrame] + ".gif"))
    self.label["image"] = self.img

    if atualFrame == len(imagesFiles) - 1:
        atualFrame = 0

    atualFrame += 1

    self.after(100, lambda: changeFrames(self))


class mainPage(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        getImageList()

        self.label = tk.Label(self)
        self.label.pack()

        changeFrames(self)

app = mainPage()
#app.geometry("600x600")
#app.config(cursor = "none")
#SET FULLSCREEN
#app.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's what I did, in image function all the frames of the gif is appended in giflist and then in Run function the gif image and the time is packed in the for loop with 0.1s delay.

Comment: Oh man, i saw the error... is time.sleep, i will change the answer

Comment: Thanks alot. The second error was that for init I used _ instead of __